# Regex to remove non-numeric characters but not at the beginning of a string

Tags: php, regex

I need to construct a regular expression (`preg_replace`) to remove all non-numeric characters from a string, but not if they occur at the beginning. I'm usually very good at constructing regular expressions but this one really had me stumbled.

An okay string follows this pattern:

```
^(SI?)?\d+$
```

For example: `SI234965305843453`

So if I'd give it this string: `S234---9Sptreccc6543453`
then the `preg_replace` should return:

**`S23496543453`**

Comment: why not apply the keep-only-digits regex to the `substr($your_var,1);`  and concat?

Answer (score 2):

Without lookaheads you can use this simple matching group and back-reference:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(.)\D+/', '$1', $str);
//=> S23496543453
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZ8kB5/1)

`(.)` before `\D+` will make sure that `\D+` doesn't match at start.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below negative lookbehind based regex to match all the non-numeric characters but not the one at the start.

```
(?<!^)\D
```

`(?<!^)` negative lookbehind which asserts that the characters going to be matched won't be preceded by the start of a line anchor.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bB9wT0/1)

```
echo preg_replace('~(?<!^)\D~', '', 'S234---9Sptreccc6543453');
//=> S23496543453
```

**Update:**

To do the replacement only on the lines which starts with `S` or `SI`.

```
$str = <<<EOT
SI234965305843453
S234---9Sptreccc6543453
5492353ffsdkfjsd5345
EOT;
echo preg_replace('~((?:^SI?|\G)\d*)[^\n\d]~m', '\1', $str);
```

**Output:**

```
S234965305843453
S23496543453
5492353ffsdkfjsd5345
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rK8vQ0/1)

Comment: Very clean with the negative lookbehind! I don't think you can do it simpler :D

Comment: How does this make sure to allow for both "SI" and "S" at the beginning of the string?

Comment: you the one say not the character which was at the start.@silkfire i don't know what exactly you mean by the above comment. Post an example along with expected output.

Comment: did you want to do the replacement on strings which starts with `S` or `SI`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj If you see my regex, a valid serial looks like this: `^(SI?)?\d+$`, i.e. the letter 'I' after the inititial 'S' is optional, 'SI' is also optional, but a serial cannot start with just 'I'.

Comment: did you want to do the replacement only on  the lines which starts with S or SI?

Comment: @AvinashRaj No, on the entire string. So if the input is without the prefix, it shall remove the non-numeric characters as well: `5492353ffsdkfjsd5345 => 54923535345`